# Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations with monorepo and @typescript-eslint/utils

Tags: typescript

The issue is simple but I don't know how to resolve it...

When I use [@typescript-eslint/utils](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/main/packages/utils), the error `Cannot find module @typescript-eslint/utils or its corresponding type declarations` occurred.

The project structure is

```
.
├── packages/
│   └── eslint-plugin-foo/
│       ├── node_modules/
│       │   └── @typescript-eslint/
│       │       └── utils
│       ├── src/
│       │   └── rules/
│       │       └── some-rule.ts
│       └── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

`some-rule.ts` imports the package like

```js
// some-rule.ts

// error: Cannot find module @typescript-eslint/utils or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)
import { ESLintUtils, TSESTree } from '@typescript-eslint/utils';
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

...
```

Following is the package's structure.

```
.
└── node_modules/
    └── @typescript-eslint/
        └── utils/
            ├── dist/
            │   ├── index.d.ts
            │   ├── index.js
            │   └── ...
            └── package.json
```

And the following json is the package.json of `@typescript-eslint/utils`.

```json
{
  "name": "@typescript-eslint/utils",
  "version": "6.8.0",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "_ts4.3",
    "package.json",
    "README.md",
    "LICENSE"
  ],
  "type": "commonjs",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/index.js"
    },
    "./ast-utils": {
      "types": "./dist/ast-utils/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/ast-utils/index.js"
    },
    "./eslint-utils": {
      "types": "./dist/eslint-utils/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/eslint-utils/index.js"
    },
    "./eslint-utils/rule-tester": {
      "types": "./dist/eslint-utils/rule-tester/RuleTester.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/eslint-utils/rule-tester/RuleTester.js"
    },
    "./json-schema": {
      "types": "./dist/json-schema.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/json-schema.js"
    },
    "./ts-eslint": {
      "types": "./dist/ts-eslint/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/ts-eslint/index.js"
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eslint-community/eslint-utils": "^4.4.0",
    "@types/json-schema": "^7.0.12",
    "@types/semver": "^7.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/scope-manager": "6.8.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/types": "6.8.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree": "6.8.0",
    "semver": "^7.5.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.8.0",
    "downlevel-dts": "*",
    "jest": "29.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "rimraf": "*",
    "typescript": "*"
  }
}
```

When I use the package like,

```js
import { ESLintUtils, TSESTree } from '@typescript-eslint/utils/dist';

...
```

the error disappear. But when I run a test for it, the following error shown

```
Package subpath './dist' is not defined by "exports" in somepath/packages/eslint-plugin-foo/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils/package.json
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [pinned post on the typescript-eslint issue tracker](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/7284): *`Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/*' or its corresponding type declarations`*.

> **This is not a bug.** We intentionally dropped support in v6 for Node <16 as [those versions of node are EOL](https://endoflife.date/nodejs). [v6 uses package.json exports](https://typescript-eslint.io/blog/announcing-typescript-eslint-v6/#package-exports) - which requires Node 16+ and isn't supported by that older module resolution strategy.
>
> **To fix the issue**, switch your TSConfig's module resolution to a newer version, most likely `"bundler"`, `"node16"`, or `"nodenext"`. See the [aka.ms/tsconfig `"moduleResolution"` docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution) for more information.
>
> See [TypeScript's new modules reference docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/introduction.html) for more information.

Comment: wow, thanks !!!! I already saw your isssue in @typescript-eslit and it was very helpfule :), thanks to for your answer for this question :)

Comment: <3 my pleasure, glad it's helpful!